# Why are there suddenly binary journals in my JES job output?

Tags: batch-processing, mainframe

When using SDSF on the mainframe to view the output of my batch jobs, I've always used the action character `s` to concatenate all the various members into one, since it's easier to see the whole job output together:

```
SDSF STATUS DISPLAY ALL CLASSES    
COMMAND INPUT ===>                 
PREFIX=*  DEST=(ALL)  OWNER=PAX
NP   JOBNAME  JobID    Owner    Prt
     PAX      TSU39756 PAX        1
s_   PAXJOB01 JOB39757 PAX         
     PAXJOB02 JOB39759 PAX
```

I've done this manually but also with scripts running on Linux to screen-scrape job output for automated status updates.

However, just today, I started seeing binary information in that output and went investigating (using `?` instead of `s`, to get a list of all related members). There are some members that I've never seen before:

```
SDSF JOB DATA SET DISPLAY - JOB PAXJOB01 (JOB39757)  
COMMAND INPUT ===>                                   
PREFIX=*  DEST=(ALL)  OWNER=PAX  SYSNAME=*       
NP   DDNAME   StepName ProcStep DSID Owner    C Dest 
     JESJCLIN                      1 PAX      A      
     JESMSGLG JES2                 2 PAX      A LOCAL
     JESJCL   JES2                 3 PAX      A LOCAL
     JESYSMSG JES2                 4 PAX      A LOCAL
     $INTTEXT JES2                 5 PAX      A      
     $JOURNAL                      6 PAX      A      
     STDIN    RUNLOG             101 PAX      A      
     STDOUT   RUNLOG             102 PAX      A LOCAL
```

Specifically, `JESJCLIN`, `$INTTEXT`, `$JOURNAL` and `STDIN` are the members that are new, and the journal is the one containing the binary information.

I want to know what controls this behaviour since it's screwing up my automated processes. I'd rather not have to `?` in to the above screen and extract only the outputs I'm interested in since that will change per job and require some heavy configuration - it's far easier to get the concatenated job output, provided I can get back to the original behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is controlled by the command `INPUT ON|OFF`.

With `INPUT ON`, it will list (and combine when using `s`) the input and output members. With `INPUT OFF`, it will simply list and combine the output members.

So, in order to ensure you only see the output members, execute `INPUT OFF` before selecting the job.